# Remove a substring from a string based on the new line delimiter

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to write a realtime visual program where text appears on the screen such like a typewritting effect. I want to be able to delete the first line of text based on the newline *('\n')* delimiter when the text height reaches a certain point.

How would you remove a line from a paragraph based on a newline?

I am tyring to use:

```
myIncreasingString.erase(std::remove(myIncreasingString.begin(), myIncreasingString.end(), "/n");
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that this myIncreasingString has new characters added to it within a loop.

Comment: Do you need all lines to be in one `std::string`? If so, `find` can be used to find the first `\n`. If not, you could store the lines in a `std::list<std::string>` or `std::vector<std::string>` and just erase the first element when you need to remove the first line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have one large string already stored and I am slowly filling up **myIncreasingString** with each character frame by frame. once the text drawn to screen is of a certain height I want to then delete the first line and continue to add characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::string`s `find` member function to find the position of the first `\n` and then its `erase` function to erase all `char`s from `begin()` to (and including) the found position.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

void remove_first_line(std::string& s) {
    if(auto idx = s.find('\n'); idx != std::string::npos) {
        s.erase(s.begin(), std::next(s.begin(), idx+1));
    }
}

int main() {  
    std::string text = "hello\nworld\nthis\nis\nfun\n";
    std::cout << "----- before ----\n";
    std::cout << text;
    remove_first_line(text);
    std::cout << "----- after ----\n";
    std::cout << text;
}
```

Output:

```
----- before ----
hello
world
this
is
fun
----- after ----
world
this
is
fun
```